# Python parse inconsistent free form street names using regex

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

For data in the following structure I want to obtain the parsed street name details:

```
# streetname 1() refers to house number 1 with an empty () additional qualifier 

keyword_token: street name 4()
keyword_token: street-name 14()

keyword_token: streetname 123()keyword_token: streetname 123()
# why is it logged one message per line, but we get the address logged twice - sometimes??

keyword_token: streetname 9(7)keyword_token: streetname 9(7)
keyword_token: streetname 27()\r\n a lot more text and log messages in the free form text log - one messageper line  \n
    
keyword_token: street-name 1-23(BLOCK D HAUS 6)keyword_token: street-name 1-23(BLOCK H HAUS 2)keyword_token: street-name 1-23(BLOCK G HAUS 3)',
```

The ideall expected result is:
3 fields for each record:

- street name
- house number
- additional qualifier (empty/NaN) if it is empty/missing

So far I experimented with the regex of: `keyword_token(.*)`, but this is giving the whole line after the keyword token.

Complications:

- I am only interested in the first match (not many) i..e only the first occurence of `keyword_token:`
- the street name itself can be quite inconsistent (spaces, -) it will start after the `keyword_token:`  and go until the `(`

> edit: an example regex101 is found here https://regex101.com/r/ueEfNU/1

> edit 2: also not numeric house numbers need to be supported.

```
keyword_token: street_name 32a()
```

Comment: Try `keyword_token:\s*(.*?)\s*(\d+)\(([^()]*)\)`, see https://regex101.com/r/iBHy6x/1

Comment: Great. That works already 93% of the time. Let me analyze the edge cases and refine the question.

Comment: Your suggested regex only works for integer (`\d+`) house numbers. Unfortunately, sometimes the data is a mixup: `32a()`. Could this be incorporated as well? I will update the data in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
keyword_token:\s*(.*?)\s*(\d[a-zA-Z\d-]*)\(([^()]*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBHy6x/3). *Details*:

- `keyword_token:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (due to `*?` lazy quantifier)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d[a-zA-Z\d-]*)` - Group 2: a digit and then zero or more letters, digits or `-` char
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 3: one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: I found one more edge case though: `keyword_token: Streetname 96-98(13) `

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I updated the solution in the answer.

Comment: Awesome - and very elegant.